# Unable to launch google.com inside Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu Linux VM in my Windows XP box.

I am able to open http://google.com on Windows XP but when I login to, Ubuntu linux.. and launch this site: I am getting an error: Server not found.

The network settings I have on LinuxUbuntu VM is :

- Adapter1 : attached to Bridge adapter.

I tried NAT as well. But nothing seems to work.

I am not in China. I provide google.com as mere example. We have a test website which cannot be launched inside Linux Ubuntu.

---

I deleted `etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. But this does not help.

The output of `ifconfig -a` and `lspci` within Ubuntu is below

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:80:0a:92 
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe80:a92/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1697396 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:132043 (132.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:20424 (20.4 KB)  TX bytes:20424 (20.4 KB)

The output of ipconfig from the host (win XP) box is
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.43.68.141
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.43.68.5

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Comment: Anuradha, please go back to [SO] and register your account there. Then, log in with the same account here, and you can edit your question again. Please don't post answers below to reply to others — you first need your account fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem in the same configuration. 
The solution was deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, Linux configures it on the next boot.

For further investigation, please supply `ifconfig -a` and `lspci` from Ubuntu and `ipconfig` from the host.